# Why does default argument have a value that is not given explicitly?

Tags: python

I have this minimal example:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, args = []):
        print(args)
        self.data = args

for _ in range(2):
    foo = Foo()
    foo.data.append(True)
```

I would expect that variable `foo` gets assigned a fresh `Foo` instance with empty data on every loop execution. Instead it outputs:

```
[]
[True]
```

Why does the second call to `Foo`s constructor have an `args` that is not []?

Comment: Because you're setting it with foo.data.append(True) ? Oh, I see the problem, nevermind

Comment: Ok, from now on I'll use None as default argument and assign values depending on that.